# How to do "artefact promotion" for NextJS?

Tags: next.js, devops, release-management

I am building a CI/CD pipeline for a product and am confused about a few things.

I have so far worked in a system where I used to do "code promotion" for environment progression ie each branch pointed towards a certain env and PRs between the branches but very recently I read about "artifact promotion" and I feel like it is a sensible thing to do and want to give it a try.

Now for my microservices, I am able to manage it by keeping a Docker image for each env, free from any env specific variables, and supplying env variables to my pod directly. It all works. But for my frontend, I am hosting it using S3 & CloudFront and I am using Next JS f/w and the way env variables work in Next JS is that we need to supply them at build time and they get embedded in the export/dist.

How do I do "artifact promotion" in such cases, specially when the env variables are different for each environment.

PS: I know this question is very specific to my use case. Apologies if I am asking it at a wrong place!

Comment: This is the fundamental problem with the build-time configuration approach. You _can't_ just promote a single artefact, because any new environment with new configuration needs a new build. You have to be disciplined and _not_ use `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_` in your frontend code, then have a single file served alongside that you can trivially switch out and/or expose an API endpoint the frontend can hit for relevant configuration. I've written more about this here: https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2020/Sep/19/spa-config.html.

Comment: It is a nice idea. Instead of an API, I might be able to embed env configs to headers or body directly by using a Lambda@Edge. How does that sound?